# Different sized subplot in tex file

Tags: subplot

I am looking for a way to create subplot like following

[image]

I have created a fig_subplot.tex file

```
\begin{subfigure}[b]{.48\linewidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=.99\textwidth]{1.eps}
  \end{subfigure}%   
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{.48\linewidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=.99\textwidth]{2.eps}
  \end{subfigure}\\%  
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{.48\linewidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=.99\textwidth]{3.eps}
  \end{subfigure}%
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{.48\linewidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=.99\textwidth]{4.eps}
  \end{subfigure}%
```

and addede it to my main.tex file

```
\begin{figure}[htb]
\centering
\input{fig_subplot}
\caption{4x4 grid}\label{fig:3}
\end{figure}
```

But how do I add tall rectangular box labeled "5" in my fig_subplot.tex.

Comment: You could arrange the plots in a tabular with a multirow for the 5th plot.

Comment: or I create a table with two columns. In 1st column, insert 4x4 grid and 2nd gets "5".

Comment: Yes, that should also work, may however require more adjustments of the colsep.

Comment: Is there any possibility of getting desired result with **subfigure** option?

Comment: Cant you put subfigures in a tabular? (I always get confused because there are too many subfigure packages around. If it does not work with your version of subfigure, you could just use `\captionof`.)

Answer (score 1):

Place the 4x4 grid in a `minipage` with `b` alignment, and add a fifth `\includegraphics` immediately after that `minipage`.  By the way, the `subfigure` environments are not really needed in your example, as you're not adding any captions to them. In the code below I added a second example without the `subfigure`s.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.8\linewidth}
\begin{subfigure}[b]{.48\linewidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=.99\textwidth]{example-image}
  \end{subfigure}%   
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{.48\linewidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=.99\textwidth]{example-image-a}
  \end{subfigure}\\%  
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{.48\linewidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=.99\textwidth]{example-image-b}
  \end{subfigure}%
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{.48\linewidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=.99\textwidth]{example-image-c}
  \end{subfigure}%
\end{minipage}%
\includegraphics[width=0.17\linewidth,height=6.9cm]{example-image-10x16}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.8\linewidth}
    \includegraphics[width=.49\textwidth]{example-image}
    \includegraphics[width=.49\textwidth]{example-image-a} 

    \vspace{2pt}

    \includegraphics[width=.49\textwidth]{example-image-b}
    \includegraphics[width=.49\textwidth]{example-image-c}
\end{minipage}
\includegraphics[width=0.17\linewidth,height=7.2cm]{example-image-10x16}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

In the above code I set the size of the tall image manually. It is however possible to get the correct height without trial and error, by putting the `minipage` in a box, and using the height of that box. An example:

```
\begin{figure}
\centering
\newsavebox\ImageGrid % define a new savebox
\sbox{\ImageGrid}{% save the minipage with gridded images in box
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.8\linewidth}
    \includegraphics[width=.49\textwidth]{example-image}
    \includegraphics[width=.49\textwidth]{example-image-a} 

    \vspace{2pt}

    \includegraphics[width=.49\textwidth]{example-image-b}
    \includegraphics[width=.49\textwidth]{example-image-c}
\end{minipage}}%
\usebox\ImageGrid % typeset the box
\includegraphics[width=0.17\linewidth,height=\ht\ImageGrid]{example-image-10x16} % use \ht (height) of box for image height
\end{figure}
```